# CakePHP 2.6 delete in transaction

Tags: cakephp, transactions

I need to delete rows and after insert data, but this operations should be grouped in one transaction.

Am I wrong or `atomic => false` param cannot be set to `Model::delete()` ?

Any advice?

Comment: Atomic isn't supported by 2.6, but is in 3.0.

Comment: Yes, it's avaliable in 3.0, but it's not easy the migration process.

Comment: I'm looking over the whole 2.6 api searching for some line that start a transaction in delete operation and at least for now I have found nothing. So if I start a transaction, delete rows and rollback should be work and the rows shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your delete and insert statements into a [transaction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html). You can build in checks to see if the delete and insert were both successful and rollback the transaction if they were not. So you'll end up with something like this in your model:

```
public function deleteAndInsert($deleteId, $newData) {
    $dataSource = $this->getDataSource();
    $dataSource->begin();

    if (!$this->delete($deleteId)) {
        // The delete failed, rollback
        $dataSource->rollback();
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->save($newData)) {
        // The save failed, rollback
        $dataSource->rollback();
        return false;
    }

    // Everything seems to be fine, commit the transaction
    $dataSource->commit();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expand on Oldskools answer. While it will work fine, it doesn't give you much of a chance to report on where the error has ocurred, or give you the option to undo potentially other things before returning a generic false value. I would implement some exception handling here, and then you would have more options to handle the failure.

```
public function deleteAndInsert($deleteId, $newData) {
    $dataSource = $this->getDataSource();

    try {
        $dataSource->begin();

        if (!$this->delete($deleteId)) {
           throw new Exception('Error deleting ID');
        }

        if (!$this->save($newData)) {
            throw new Exception('Error Storing new data');
        }

        $dataSource->commit();
        return 'Action completed successfully';

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $dataSource->rollback();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, this gives better possiblities for error reporting and handling. +1!

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time but... although it is true that the `'atomic'` option is not supported, `Model::delete()` does not seem to imply a commit, so there's actually no need for it, as the examples prove.
I also believe that the previous answers work only because they involve a single Model (no associations).
Without:

```
    if (!$this->save($newData,['atomic'=>false)) {
        throw new Exception('Error Storing new data');
    }
```

INSERTs and UPDATEs of associated models will be atomic transactions.